# how to make dynamic form from API response in angular 7?

Tags: angular, angular7, angular-reactive-forms, dynamic-forms, form-control

I'm working on dynamic form in angular 7. I have followed the way which is mentioned on angular official website. I successfully implemented that tutorial but my scenario is different. what kind of input will be there in form and all its attribute will come from a API response

this is the function in service which brings my data. 
Please note: On the basis of API data i will populate my questions array, for now i used dummy data just to make sure flow is working. this is how my question.service.ts looks like

```
public response : QuestionBase<any>[] =[];      
getQuestions(id) {
  this.http.get(this.url+'selectAllFieldDetails/'+id)
.pipe(map(
( response: Response) => {
    let data = response;
    console.log(data);


   let questions: QuestionBase<any>[] = [

      new DropdownQuestion({
        key: 'brave',
        label: 'Bravery Ratings',
        class:'form-control fis-form-control',
        formclass:'',
        options: [
          {key: 'solid',  value: 'Solid'},
          {key: 'great',  value: 'Great'},
          {key: 'good',   value: 'Good'},
          {key: 'unproven', value: 'Unproven'}
        ],
        required: true,
        order: 2
      }),

      new TextboxQuestion({
        key: 'process',
        label: 'Process name',
        value: 'IT ',
        class:'form-control fis-form-control',
        formclass:'',
        required: true,
        order: 1
      }),


    ];
    this.response =  questions.sort((a, b) => a.order - b.order);
   }
  ));
  console.log(this.response);
  return this.response;
}
```

But problem is function return before the API response and it return empty array. This is the way i'm calling from create-ticket.component.ts

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.questions = this.service.getQuestions(24);
  console.log(this.questions);
}
```

Somehow i tried to get the API response first and store it in some variable  and then calling this function this.service.getQuestions(24); but then it shows error that

```
Error: Cannot find control with name: 'process'
at _throwError (forms.js:1775)
at setUpControl (forms.js:1683)
at FormGroupDirective.push../node_modules/@angular/forms/fesm5/forms.js.FormGroupDirective.addControl (forms.js:4532)
at FormControlName.push../node_modules/@angular/forms/fesm5/forms.js.FormControlName._setUpControl (forms.js:5030)
at FormControlName.push../node_modules/@angular/forms/fesm5/forms.js.FormControlName.ngOnChanges (forms.js:4980)
at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (core.js:9239)
at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.js:10507)
at checkAndUpdateNode (core.js:10469)
at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (core.js:11102)
at debugCheckDirectivesFn (core.js:11062)
```

and Formgorup data remains empty. 
Please help me in this problem.
Thanks in advance

Comment: please provide all code or even better a stackblitz for minimal troubleshooting.

Comment: and the problem is :  you are not subscribing to the get request in order to lauch the request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So finally after a long r&d I have done this. basically there was two problem

1. function in service respond before the API response
2. form get created before the data come into business

So for first issue i used the concept of `async await` feature in angular

In the create-ticket.component.ts we added async and await like this.

```
async ngOnInit() {
    this.questions = await this.service.getQuestionss(24);
    if(this.questions.length>0){
       this.showForm=true;
    }
}
```

and in service we return a promise

```
async getQuestionss(id): Promise<any> {
     this.responses = await this.apiServce.getAllInputFields(id).toPromise();
}
```

it responds as a promise so it wait till the api response. `this.apiservice.getAllInputFields(id)` is just a http api call from server.

For 2nd problem i used just a small solution. i added *ngIf in form so when the api respond with data then only form start to build.

```
<app-dynamic-forms *ngIf="showForm" [questions]="questions"></app-dynamic-forms>
```

Thats all and problem resolved.

Answer (score 1):

outdated info based on stackblitz

> You should should always subscribe to an async call in order for it to
>   be executed
>
> ```
> ngOnInit() {
>   this.questions = this.service.getQuestions(24).subscribe(result => {
>                 do something with result }, 
>       err => { something went wrong });
> }
> ```

Here is a stackblitz, based on yours :
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-h8zakj?embed=1&file=src/app/question.service.ts

as I said there was an issue with your setTimeout. the data was not accessible where you wanted it.

Comment: property subscribe does not exist on type  QuestionBase<any>[]. this is my questionbase interface.  export class QuestionBase<T> {
  value: T;
  key: string;
  label: string;
  required: boolean;
  order: number;
  class:string;
  controlType: string;
  formclass: string;
  constructor(options: {
      value?: T,
      key?: string,
      label?: string,
      required?: boolean,
      order?: number,
      class?: string,
      formclass?: string,
      controlType?: string
    } = {}) {
   
  }
}

Comment: yes he should return the thiis.http.get call as an observable from his service and change the return type.  anyway he has mixed a lot of incomplete stuff. this is why i requested mode code

Comment: you can see here https://angular.io/generated/live-examples/dynamic-form/stackblitz.html

Comment: he should return      `getQuestions(id) {
  this.http.get(this.url+'selectAllFieldDetails/'+id)
.pipe(map(    ... `  as an observable  in the end.    for now he needs to retuen an observable of his dummy data to get this working

Comment: Best is for him to make a stack blitz with mock data.  (not http call with mock data, half and half)/ make the example to be based on observables of your current type and subscribe to it. once you receive the data generate the form

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ytkydp this is the url for the editor. you can see the issue what i m facing. I have called settimeout function instead of http call  because the behavior is same. if you remove the settimeout function then form will appear.

Comment: it seems that  `this.form = this.qcs.toFormGroup(this.questions);` just returns empty controls

Comment: the setTimeout you have used in your service breaks to whole thing, and doesnt  return anything.  remove it and you get data and an actual form

Comment: i have added this settimeout purposely. because it behave like an API call as an api call also take some time to respond. i was not able to add httpclient there so i added settimeout so you can see the behavior. and suggest me some solution. you can also edit there.

Comment: Some quick tests didn't work out on stackblitz. don;t know why.   anyway, its not related to the initial question anymore in my opninion

Comment: i did it.. some how i succeeded to do this using async and await.. now my form waits till the api response. `question.service.ts:85 {status: "success", message: "success", data: Array(3)}create-ticket.component.ts:25 (4) [TextboxQuestion, DropdownQuestion, TextboxQuestion, TextboxQuestion]`
Now I'm stuck with formcontrol error.
     `Error: Cannot find control with name: 'process'
at _throwError (forms.js:1775)
at setUpControl (forms.js:1683)
at FormGroupDirective.push../node_modules/@angular/forms/fesm5/forms.js.FormGroupDirective.addControl (forms.js:4532)
at Form`